# filterLogging not working on Database.Persist.Sql's runSqlPool function

Tags: sql, haskell, logging, persistent, monad-transformers

The Haskell library Database.Persist.Sqlite includes functions that run within a LoggingT context, to control debugging output.  So I expected to be able to limit the debugging output they produce, thus:

```
runStdoutLoggingT . filterLogger (\_ _ -> False) (runSqlPool (insertBy myData) myPool)
```

(condensed and simplified from my actual code) However, it doesn't suppress logging.  The evalation of insertBy produces a line on stdout of the form

```
[Debug#SQL] SELECT "id","key","data_source_row_id","loaded" FROM "data_row" WHERE "key"=? AND "data_source_row_id"=?; [PersistText blahblahblah]
```

So why isn't the output suppressed by the filterLogger call ?

Since the question has received two downvotes, I'll add that the pattern shown above (i.e., runStdoutLoggingT . filterLogger) is used in many GitHub projects and I can't see how my application is any different.  It is somewhat frustrating to be downvoted without explanation or means of recourse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The architecture of Persistent is a little circuitous and underdocumented:

- `withSqlPool` takes a builder. The builder is able to build a `SqlBackend` out of any "logging function" (basically the internal type that MonadLogger uses). The function then creates a *resource pool* of `SqlBackend`s, for you to acquire and release and use. This is the continuation argument `Pool SqlBackend -> m a` you pass in. In return, `withSqlPool` promises to give you back a bunch of side effects, typed as `(MonadIO m, MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadLogger m) => m a`.
- `runSqlPool`, on the other hand, takes a `MonadBaseControl IO m => ReaderT SqlBackend m a` and a `Pool SqlBackend` and returns `m a`. We can infer from this that it basically acquires a `SqlBackend` from the resource pool, uses it to construct and run a SQL query, and then returns `MonadBaseControl IO => m a`. Indeed, its documentation is "Get a connection from the pool, run the given action, and then return the connection to the pool."

Though named similarly, they do two very different things. The first function constructs the resource pool and the second function uses it. Most Persistent SQL code will have this shape:

```
withSqlPool (\logFunc -> do
                conn <- makeConnection connectionString
                return SqlBackend { ... , connLogFunc = logFunc })
            numberOfOpenConnections
            (\pool -> do
              runSqlPool (insertBy myData) pool
              runSqlPool (anotherTransaction moreData) pool)
```

In fact, if you're using `persistent-postgresql`, the above is simply the expanded form of

```
withPostgresqlPool connectionString
                   numberOfOpenConnections
                   (\pool -> do
                     runSqlPool (insertBy myData) pool
                     runSqlPool (anotherTransaction moreData) pool)
```

But wait! We can't quite execute this as an `IO` action yet. `MonadIO m, MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadLogger m` are our constraints and it's that third one that we have to discharge:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  runStdoutLoggingT $
    withPostgresqlPool connectionString
                       numberOfOpenConnections
                       (\pool -> do
                         runSqlPool (insertBy myData) pool
                         runSqlPool (anotherTransaction moreData) pool
                         return ())
```

When the third constraints disappears, we're able to unify `IO ()` with `(MonadIO m, MonadBaseControl IO m) => m ()` by realizing `m ~ IO`.

It's now, at this stage, that we're able to insert our `filterLogger` – right before the constraint is discharged with `runStdoutLoggingT`:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  runStdoutLoggingT . filterLogger (\_ _ -> False) $
    withPostgresqlPool connectionString
                       numberOfOpenConnections
                       (\pool -> do
                         runSqlPool (insertBy myData) pool
                         runSqlPool (anotherTransaction moreData) pool
                         return ())
```

Overall, a mess created by bad naming and the underwhelmingly documented `Database.Persist.Sql` module.

**Let's underline the point: `runSqlPool` simply inherits the logging behavior from the `MonadLogger` constraint generated by `withSqlPool`. It is only at the `withSqlPool` level that we're able to insert the desired `filterLogger` call.**

Comment: Thank you for that very detailed and helpful reply. I confirm your answer is correct because I put the filterLogger around the call to createSqlitePool and it controls logging in the way I want. Haskell continues to confound me in some respects but that's what makes it so interesting. It is necessary to think of runStdoutLoggingT as adding concrete behaviour to an abstract interface, rather than as I was thinking, which was that is does all the logging at that point and returns an object with no logging behaviour.